# Is it possible to NGen dlls for use in Azure Websites?

Tags: azure, ngen

We are currently using MVC3, .NET4.5, EF6.1, MSSQL2008(dev), SQL Azure(Test and Live). Our application is quite complicated and we are encountering significant warm up lags, around 30 secs, after an application pool refresh. We use External autoping services to keep the sites warm, which are OKish.... However it would be a much better solution to just deploy native images, and then whenever a app pool refreshes for whatever reasons, we know the application will load as quickly as possible.

Hence the reason for investigating NGEN.

However I am unsure whether this is possible for Azure Websites. Some questions I have:

1) NGen requires Admin privilege. As I understand it I would need admin privilege to install Native images to Azure Websites, or can I generate them on a local "same cpu" machine and copy them across?

2) Require Full Trust now. I believe this is no issue with WAWS.

3) Does NGen only install in Cache and not produce some sort of file for copying to a different location?

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can NGEN be used with Azure Websites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736839/can-ngen-be-used-with-azure-websites)