# Can NGEN be used with Azure Websites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, ngen

After much research I still cannot find the answer to this question.

So can one NGEN one's ASP.NET MVC3 application which is deployed in Azure Websites, in a 32bit "Basic" or "Standard" instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will things blow up if you NGEN?  No.

Will you get a benefit from NGEN?  No.  If your build system differs from the Azure server (which almost certainly does), the runtime will simply re-JIT things on the server.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am attempting to avoid startup delays, especially when using "autoscaling". I am a little nervous as the "Cloud" setup means app pools can refresh more often as instances get brought on line by Azure. Thus my reasoning was to have native code which could startup very quickly. I understand about the platforms. Can one not NGEN for a particular target ie Windows Server 2012, and then move that ni.dll across to Azure. Altneratively one could create a 2012 VM server locally for creating Native images on, but that is more involved.

Comment: The real question is why Azure Web Apps don't do any ngen of the deployed dlls themselves.